# Não consigo trazer as informações da database para o checkbox e trazer os valores dele

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, firebase

Estou fazendo um projeto de crud no qual eu preciso marcar as tecnologias que serão utilizadas. Eu faço esse cadastro das tecnologias e gostaria de puxar do banco de dados as informações, porém ao fazer isso eu só receber o value como true no cadastro

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4" *ngFor="let item of tecnologias">
      <div class="check-container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="html" class="checkbox" formControlName='tecnologia'>
        <label>{{item.tecnologia}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

e aqui o component.ts

tecnologias!: Tecnologias[];

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  nome: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(100),
      Validators.pattern(/^(?!À-Ö)[A-Za-z\',\-àáâãçèéêẽíôõóúû ]*$/),
    ],
  ],
  formacao: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(/^(?!À-Ö)[A-Za-z\',\-àáâãçèéêẽíôõóúû ]*$/),
    ],
  ],
  email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
  contato: ['', [Validators.required]],
  tecnologia: [''],
});
```

```
cadastrarProfessor() {
    const professor: Professor = {
      nome: this.form.value.nome,
      formacao: this.form.value.formacao,
      email: this.form.value.email,
      contato: this.form.value.contato,
      tecnologia: this.form.value.tecnologia,
    };
    this.service.addProfessor(professor).then(
      () => {
        console.log('Sucesso!');
        this.route.navigate(['/professor/lista'])
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
```

Alguém tem alguma solução? Tenho visto muito utilizando FormArrayName porém não consegui colocar em prática

Comment: Você precisa colocar um campo [value] no checkbox, para informar qual o valor daquele campo. Se o retorno da sua base de dados for o mesmo que o value, o checkbox fica marcado automaticamente.

Answer (score -3):

Tem algumas maneiras de você encarar esse problema. Você pode tirar ele do fluxo do reactive forms do angular e tratar ele por fora (utilizando two-way data binding nos checkboxes, atualizando listas no controller com (change) do input, ou até com ids dinâmicos e buscando elementos com as APIs do document) ou você pode manter os checkboxes dentro do FormGroup e utilizar o FormArray.

Caso você queira utilizar o FormArray, dá uma olhada nesse StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ebjvea

Ao apertar "enviar", ele deve logar os objetos das checkboxes selecionadas.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).